# Choosing map serving software

Tags: web-mapping, software-recommendations

I'm new to GIS and need to learn for an internship. I've been reading a lot and now need help picking technologies to use... particularly the map serving technologies.

Project requirements -

- Free
- Web Based Service
- Able to display layers/features over Google Maps/Bing Maps
- Able to select individual features/layers (Seems like open layers does this?)

  - e.g. select individual/multiple points/polygons
- Works on 64 bit Red Hat
- Compatible with PHP, PostGIS (seems like they all do)

What I've narrowed it down to so far...

GeoServer - Seems to be the easiest to learn and install. Not sure if I can use Google Maps with it though. Maybe with a WFS? Most questions tagged on this site.

MapServer - Seems tricky to install on 64 bit. (No MapTools FGS yet for 64 bit) 2nd most questions tagged on this site.

MapGuide - Looks cool and has cool features but it looks "youngest" and the documentation is behind so it might be hard to get things going fast. (by the time the internships over.) Least most tagged.