# Developing Web Application For Map

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, mapinfo, postgresql

I have huge data of maps usually most of the table are co-ordinates and the other are raster maps stored in SQL server 2008 and PostGres Server. I am using desktop application to analyse the data. Usually the desktop end is QGIS or mapinfo. Now I think It would be easier if end user could do the same with the same dataset. So I am building a web application so that those data could be queried and manipulated by end user as required and view as layer. How to get started with this? I had a look at  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054931/web-based-map-application-development) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570394/where-to-start-with-map-application).

> The requirement :

1. User should be able to query data from server and display it as map.
2. Since there are multiple tables they should come as multiple layers and user can disable and enable the layer.
3. There is no relation what so ever with google/bing/or third party maps ( may be this could be quite a feature for version 2)

Actually I want to build simple web application that acts as basic GIS application. Well tell me if I am reinventing the wheel.

I found this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/key-features-of-a-web-map/1023#1023) helpful but could not provide step by step solution to the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Completely brand new to GIS - Help picking technology from the pros](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12353/completely-brand-new-to-gis-help-picking-technology-from-the-pros) and [Where/How to Learn about Getting Started with Web GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8238/where-how-to-learn-about-getting-started-with-web-gis)

I'd also recommend the [tutorials](http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/) and [courses](https://courseware.e-education.psu.edu/courses/geog585/content/home.html) I've written as a way to get up to speed with the technology.

Comment: Is it possible to query database and create new layer ? I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: see http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver_docs/data/naturalearth/index.html for a full walk through from download to WMS output

Answer (score 2):

Mapserver, openlayers, geoext etc

Unfornately building a proper web map is nontrivial, requiring root access to the server to install the software stack, decent bandwidth and ram, and extensive learngin curves.

The main alternatives i can think of are gmaps/fusion tables, or openlayers alone with tms and gml layers.

Comment: fusion tables is not an alternative as I want to use with my own data and not with google maps.

Comment: Then that leaves you with mapserver et al , or pure js solutions. Try gdal2tiles to cut a large raster into TMS tile pyramids, use that for a base layer, then you can add small to mid sze vector layers as overlays using json, kml et al. All done client side.

Answer (score 1):

If the data has to be manipulated I would recommened Geomajas: http://www.geomajas.org/
Online demo's here: http://apps.geomajas.org/showcase/