# PostGIS data visualization

Tags: web-mapping, postgis-2.0

I have dump my data in PostGIS from shapefile successfully. I made a postgres connection through PHP and that also returning the data of other field. But the main problem is GEOM field visualization. I want to visualize GEOM field (Polygon and Polyline). Simply I want to visualize PostGIS data to web. Any kind of help or tutorial will be appreciated highly.

---

I am clarifying little more. I have created my own tiles with tilemill. I am now using Leaflet to visualize the tiles. I have completed this portion successfully. Now I have same database in PostGIS.

I want some interactivity with that data. Such as Search return polygon/polyline/point on the map from PostGIS database. What is the easiest way to do this. 
In future I want to integrate PGRouting with this map also.

Comment: Please read http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/how-to-start-web-mapping/8115#8115

Comment: I am clarifying little more. I have created my own tiles with tilemill. I am now using Leaflet to visualize the tiles. I have completed this portion successfully. Now I have same database in PostGIS. I want some interactivity with that data. Such as Search return polygon/polyline/point on the map from PostGIS database. What is the easiest way to do this. In future I want to integrate PGRouting with this map also. I have learned so many things from http://underdark.wordpress.com/. Thanks

Comment: You might also want to read http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15616/why-do-we-need-mapserver-geoserver-to-present-data-from-spatial-database-to-web/15619