# How to visuilze PostGIS data in GeoJSON format with PHP

Tags: geojson, postgis-2.0, php

I need to visualize PostGIS Geometry column as an overlay of a Leaflet tiled Map. I started a question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45291/postgis-data-visualization) ,but didn't get any simple and satisfied answer. So I am starting this question. I got an option on [Github](https://gist.github.com/1913855) to convert the PostGIS column to GeoJSON which can be visible through leaflet map.

I used the url as follows

```
http://localhost:8080/pgsql/PostGIS_GeoJSON.php?geotable=bgd_adm3&geomfield=geom
```

but it returns the following errors

```
Notice: Undefined index: parameters in C:\wamp\www\pgsql\PostGIS_GeoJSON.php on line 52

Notice: Undefined index: orderby in C:\wamp\www\pgsql\PostGIS_GeoJSON.php on line 54

Notice: Undefined index: limit in C:\wamp\www\pgsql\PostGIS_GeoJSON.php on line 61

Notice: Undefined index: offset in C:\wamp\www\pgsql\PostGIS_GeoJSON.php on line 63

Warning: pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: function transform(geometry, integer) does not exist LINE 1: SELECT *, st_asgeojson(transform(geom,4326)) AS geojson FROM... ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. in C:\wamp\www\pgsql\PostGIS_GeoJSON.php on line 89
An SQL error occured.
```

What I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [code you are using](https://gist.github.com/1913855) uses the older function naming style without the "ST_" prefix, used many many years ago. So `transform(geometry, integer)` is now `ST_Transform(geometry, integer)`.

There are a few things you can do to fix this. Do one of these:

- Fix the PHP code, by changing `transform` to `ST_Transform`
- Apply the `legacy.sql` enabler script from the PostGIS `contrib` directory ([documented here](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#create_new_db))

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Can you explain little more how to enable legacy.sql script from PostGIS contrib directory?

Comment: @DevilsDream updated answer. You will need to locate the `legacy.sql` for your system (it depends on what you have installed).