# save features from openlayers to postgis via nodejs and websockets

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, postgresql

I try to save features created on a vector layer (openlayers) to postgreSQL 9.1/postGIS 2.0 via websockets.

As server I use nodejs 0.10.12 along with the pg module

I cannot fix it. Its getting so overwhelming I decided to ask a new question.

The problem : I cannot pass the geometry to the server. If I pass it like WKT (a format like `POINT(122544 588788)`) client side complains about `syntax error : Converting circular structure to JSON`. And this is because I'm using `JSON Stringify` to send multiple data to the server via websockets.

So I convert feature's geometry to a string, I strip it from the letters and the parentheses and I send to the server only the numbers. I send only this `122544 588788`. In that case, JSON does not complain, but I get syntax errors on the server side, about the geometry.

Seriously, any help, suggestion or alternative would be great. I apologize for the big question. 
Here is the code

client side

```
//create websockets
var so = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000");

//error report for websockets   
      so.onerror=function (evt) 
     {saveMSG.textContent = evt;}

//get the geometry of the feature      
var jak=      map.layers[2].features[0].geometry;
//turn it to a string   
var amir=new String(jak);
//get the first five letters to check if it is line,point or polygon
var sara=amir.substring(0,5);

//if its lines....
    if(sara=='LINES'){
//get just the numbers
var hul=amir.substring(11,amir.length-1);
//open websockets connection
     so.onopen = function(){
//send the geometry's numbers, the type of the geometry and other things from a form
       so.send(JSON.stringify({   
            name: document.getElementById("name").value,
       geo: hul,
       geoT:'line',
       descr: document.getElementById("descr").value
       }));}
}

//same ifs for point or polygons....
```

and the server side

```
function insertEm(name,descr,geo,geoT){
//if line....
if(geoT=='line'){
//create the "WKT"...   
    var ste="LINESTRING("+geo+")";
//and put it in place...
    var met="ST_GeomFromWKT('LINESTRING("+ste+")',900913)";
    }

//same ifs for point or polygon

//and now do the insert...
        var conString = "pg://username:password@localhost:5432/myDB";

var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();

var query = client.query({name:"inser", text:"INSERT INTO pins(p_name, p_descr,p_geom) values($1,$2,$3)", values:[name, descr, met]});

    query.on("error", function (error) {console.log(error)});
query.on("end", function (result) {console.log(result); client.end();});
```

What I get from the server side is

```
[error: parse error - invalid geometry]
hint: '"ST"<-- parse error a position 2 within geometry'
```

I've tried different syntaxes but I cannot get it work.

---

I'm still trying. I tried a lot of things and different syntaxes. Now I have, on the server side (snippet)

```
//open websockets
 so.onopen = function(){
//get geometry      
 var jak=map.layers[2].features[0].geometry;
//make it a string      
 var as=new String(jak);
//keep the numbers      
 var hul=as.substring(11,as.length-1);
//make it WKT       
 var god=hul.toString();


//send it with stringify
       so.send(JSON.stringify({command: 'insertAll',
       geo: god,
//send other things from the form....
```

Server side (snippet)

```
//get data from client, put it in place and create a string from it
var met="ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING("+geo+")',900913)";
var pra=new String(met);

//connect and query
var conString = "pg://user:user@localhost:5432/myDB";
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();

var query = client.query({name:"inser", text:"INSERT INTO pins(p_geom) values($1)", values:[pra]});
```

And I STILL get
`[error: parse error - invalid geometry]
hint: '"ST"<-- parse error a position 2 within geometry'`

I change it to a simple query
`var query = client.query("INSERT INTO  pins (p_geom) values('"+pra+"')")`

and get `[error: syntax error at or near "LINESTRING"]`.

At the end of the query I put `query.on("end", function (result) {console.log(result);connection.send(pra); client.end();});`

So I can see what the clients send to the server.
I get `ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(2335859.0225 4725430.1340625,2378933.155 4741356.7040625)',900913)` that looks fine...

Any suggestions?

---

I used `jQuery/AJAX` and `INSERT` of `PHP`. Amazingly , still nothing.

client side

```
//get geometry
 var jak=map.layers[2].features[0].geometry;

//send      
jQuery.post("insertPPB.php", { geo, d}, function(data) {

  alert(data);
 $('#response').html(data);
  });
```

server side

```
//get geometry
$g=$_POST['g'];

//prepared statement for the insert...
$st = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO pins (p_geom) VALUES (:geo)");
$st->bindParam(':geo', $geo, PDO::PARAM_STR);

//put the geometry in place
$geo = "ST_GeomFromText('".$g.")', 900913)";
$st->execute();
$last_insert_id = $dbh->lastInsertId('pins_p_id_seq');
echo $last_insert_id;
```

If I alert the `jak` in the client side , before I send it, I get something like `LINESTRING(2328981.64 4722534.3940625,2399203.335 4706607.8240625,2405356.7825 4645435.3165625)`

That SHOULD work. Right? But it does not. The `INSERT` never happens.
I dont know what to do, I though using `AJAX/PHP` would solve this.

If this does not work can I use WFS-T? But, how can I get the newly id created in the db from the point just added? I need it to add form text data and relate them with that point. All the ids are serial (grow automatically +1 with every insert). On Geoserver I dont see the "id" in the Feature Type Details of the vector layer.

Why?

Comment: see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15616/why-do-we-need-mapserver-geoserver-to-present-data-from-spatial-database-to-web/15619#15619

Comment: You'll probably also want to read http://www.freshbrewedcodes.com/jimcowart/2013/01/29/what-you-might-not-know-about-json-stringify/ (or any other primer on stringify). Then check out GeoJSON (http://www.geojson.org/geojson-spec.html)

Comment: @iant Thanks for the hints. Can you be a little more specific? Your saying I should use Geoserver and GeoJSON?

Comment: I'd probably use WFS/T and GML as it works out of the box that way but don't let me stop you going down this route, if you choose to use JSON then GeoJSON may be of use to you.

Comment: @iant GeoJSON via websockets? Sounds...difficult. Actually the other "problem" is that later I will try to upload and save images via the same websocket connection that now handles the geometry and the form data. Anyway, thanks again. I'll study hard and let you know

Comment: Try looking into TWKB (Tiny WKB) by our own GIS-SE member Nicklas Avén http://blog.jordogskog.no/ Live Demo is available here http://178.79.156.122/twkb_node/ - websockets/twkb code http://178.79.156.122/twkb_node/twkb.js